# Mapping problem with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm working with Spring MVC. I have a controller which returns a `new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()))`. SuccessView is set as `home.htm` which is a virtual page that maps to `WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp`.

However I'm getting this error:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [`/Bikes_Spring/WEB-INF/jsp/home.htm`] in DispatcherServlet.

As you can see it's searching for home.htm inside the jsp folder... it should be `/Bikes_Spring/home.htm`

Any ideas how I could resolve this?
Thanks :)

Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

In my resolver mapping, I added `redirect:` in front of home.htm and it did the trick:

```
<property name="successView"><value>redirect:home.htm</value></property>
```

What I wanted to do was go from one controller to another... sry I'm still quite a newbie in spring...

Comment: Are you sure you have `new RedirectView(...)` in the value returned by controller, as you stated in the question? The behaviour you describes looks like it's missing.